# Chosen Plugin doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im making a website and, to make the "selects" prettier i use choosen plugin, but im up with a problem..

It seems the choosen doesn't work in mobile..

Here is the link for you in order to check:
[Website](http://www.dev.dotpro.pt/europa)

Someone as some snippet that can show me?

Comment: Chosen is not supported on android or IOS, "Chosen is disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices "

Comment: You know other plugin in order to do the same?

Comment: https://select2.github.io/ try this

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try!

Comment: select2 is good choice... i use it in corporate response layout and work fine

Comment: I would suggest you to search for related question on SO before posting, as it would save lot of time for your and for others.